# Magento 2 - Category list for custom magento system configuration section

Tags: magento2, category, system-configuration, multiselect

My problem to get all available categories and display them in a system config multi-select field list.

Here is a [link](https://developerview.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/category-list-for-custom-magento-system-configuraion-section/) for **Magento 1.x**. How can it be achieved for **Magento 2.x**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `system.xml` file field for multi select of category is like:

```
<group id="bannerblock_setting" translate="label" type="text" default="1" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Setting</label>
    <field id="bannerlist" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Select Category</label>
        <!-- <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>-->
        <source_model>Ipragmatech\Bannerblock\Model\Config\Source\Categorylist</source_model>
    </field>
</group>
```

> Create a file `Categorylist.php` in
>   `Companyname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source`

```
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Categorylist implements ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory)
    {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $catalogCategory;
    }

    /*
     * Return categories helper
     */

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }

    /*  
     * Option getter
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {


        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        {

            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /*
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {

        $categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);

        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){

            $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($category->getName());
        }

        return $catagoryList;
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

---

Comment: But in this case you'll get first level only and categories included in menu

Comment: You can little part modify code and get call subcategories..it upon you to make category and subcategory array and return that.

Comment: Hi @manish I have followed your post/answer everything working fine but we are facing an issue with displaying selected value after saving at admin end attribute level can you please suggest is there any thing  i missed it.

Answer (score 21):

VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="module_section" translate="label" type="text"
                 sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Module</label>
            <tab>tab_name</tab>
            <resource>VendorName_ModuleName::config_module_name</resource>
            <group id="module_section_page" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Module page settings</label>
                <field id="latest_category" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="12" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>New Product Category</label>
                    <source_model>VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Categorylist</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="VendorName_ModuleName::config_module_name" title="Module Section" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source/Categorylist.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Categorylist implements ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->_toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    private function _toArray()
    {
        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(true, false, false, false);

        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName());
        }

        return $catagoryList;
    }

    private function _getParentName($path = '')
    {
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1,2);

        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        // Deleting category itself
        array_pop($catTree);

        if($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats)))
        {
            foreach ($catTree as $catId)
            {
                if(!in_array($catId, $rootCats))
                {
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }

        return $parentName;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Sir can you please explain... I used the same class as you mentioned above and its works perfectly for me.. but when I submit my module to *Magento QA* they send my module back to me with a note that `dublicating the class Category.php` since I used `Category.php` in place of `Categorylist.php`

Comment: i was not looking for this particularly but this helps me in my issue. 1+ upvoted

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs more clear code, you are welcome :)

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category as CategoryHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $categoryHelper;

    /**
     * Category constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory
     */
    public function __construct(CategoryHelper $catalogCategory)
    {
        $this->categoryHelper = $catalogCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function toOptionArray(): array
    {
        $options = [];

        foreach ($this->toArray() as $key => $value) {
            $options[] = ['value' => $key, 'label' => $value,];
        }

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray(): array
    {
        $categoryList = [];

        foreach ($this->categoryHelper->getStoreCategories() as $category) {
            $categoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = $category->getName();
        }

        return $categoryList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one want code with parent and child category then follow below code :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
    * Get category collection
    *
    * @param bool $isActive
    * @param bool|int $level
    * @param bool|string $sortBy
    * @param bool|int $pageSize
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
    */
    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());


        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->_toArray();
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }    
        return $ret;
    }

    private function _toArray()
    {
        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(true, false, false, false);
        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
           $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName());
        }
        return $catagoryList;
    }

    private function _getParentName($path = '')
    {
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1,2);  
        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        array_pop($catTree);     
        if($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats))){
            foreach ($catTree as $catId){
                if(!in_array($catId, $rootCats)){
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }
        return $parentName;
    }
}
```