# Magento 2 - Drop down Customer select list

Tags: magento2, customer, system.xml

I need to grab a list with all customers in `etc\adminhtml\system.xml`, but I am not sure how.

I checked the solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110493/magento-2-category-list-for-custom-magento-system-configuration-section) that refers to the categories, but both solutions show me a blank page (I don't have enough reputation to comment on these replies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

**NOTE:** You can change class name from `Test` to anything.

app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="customer_list" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Select Customer</label>
                    <source_model>Company\Module\Model\Test</source_model>
                </field>
```

app/code/Company/Module/Model/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Test implements ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     * */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder       $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->customerRepository    = $customerRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }


    /*
     * Option getter
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /*
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $customers      = $this->customerRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

        $customersList = array();
        foreach ($customers as $customer)
        {

            $customersList[$customer->getId()] = __($customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname());
        }

        return $customersList;
    }

}
```

Comment: The solution seems correct, but just like in the other [example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110493/magento-2-category-list-for-custom-magento-system-configuration-section) I see a blank page... I used a logger and I notice that it doesn't access any of the Model's functions. If I simply make a yes/no ArrayInterface that only implements `toOptionArray()` it works correctly. Is there any chance there is a problem with the input arguments of the constructor?

Comment: I tried this code here first and its working fine.  double check model class in system.xml.. did you replace company and module from the files

Comment: It appears I had a problem with the constructor. If I remove it and get the 2 constructor's arguments through ObjectManager (which I know is a bad practice), it works properly:
`$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$searchCriteria = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')->create();
$customers = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();`
Any ideas on why there is a problem with the constructor?

Comment: Every time you inject any dependency in the constructor. You need to run these two commands afterwards.
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
if you didn't run these pls give it a shot.

Comment: Apparently I didn't. Thank you so much!