# How to show Categories in System.xml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, backend, system.xml

I'm getting all the **categories** in `System.xml` using the class

`Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source\Category`

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Category implements OptionSourceInterface{

    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    /**
    * Get category collection
    *
    * @param bool $isActive
    * @param bool|int $level
    * @param bool|string $sortBy
    * @param bool|int $pageSize
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
    */


    public function getAllCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        return $collection;
    }



    public function toOptionArray(){

        $arr = $this->_toCheckArray();
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }    
        return $ret;
    } 

    private function _toCheckArray(){

        $categories = $this->getAllCategoryCollection(true, false, false, false);
        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
           $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($this->_getCategoryParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName());
        }
        return $catagoryList;
    }



    private function _getCategoryParentName($path = ''){
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1,2);  
        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        array_pop($catTree);     
        if($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats))){
            foreach ($catTree as $catId){
                if(!in_array($catId, $rootCats)){
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }
        return $parentName;
    }
}
```

I get this class form [Magento 2 - Category list for custom magento system configuration section](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110493/magento-2-category-list-for-custom-magento-system-configuration-section?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
Now its works perfectly for me and its output is like
[image]
But when I submit my module to *Magento QA* they send me the **Error**
[image]

Now how can I solve this problem?unable to identify the problem

**Note:** I have submitted this Extension before by changing the Name of *Class* I thought that it will be the problem because of the Class name or Methods name I changed all the methods name and class name but again they send me the same problem.

Comment: Your extension is rejected due to duplicate code or you use a public function instead of private function. see this module will help you to remove duplicate code 
https://github.com/mconnectmedia/Code-Duplication-Analysis-Tool-for-Magento-2-Extension/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ChiragPatel its not working... In response it gives me "No code duplication found in your code"

Comment: If you are not getting any error or not clear about your rejection then you can email to magento market place. i have mentioned email in may answer

Comment: Yeah I already send them an Email but they are not giving me any response

Answer (score 3):

**To solve out your issue do the follow below step :**

1. [Technical Review Guidelines](https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/sellers/technical-review-guidelines.html)
2. You can email to **marketplace@magento.com** with any Marketplace submission problems. They'll be able to help you out.
3. [marketplacesupport.magento.com](https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us) From here you can create a support ticket to ask your question and you will also find more Info regarding Magento Marketplace.
4. [This are the few things I found which can help to reduce rejection and pass EQP process.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187509/how-to-create-a-marketplace-ready-magento-2-extension)

Follow the above step it might be solved out your problem.

I hope it helps!Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is happening because there is code that already does that.
Check: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Product/Form/Categories/Options.php`

Comment: yeah I get all the categories in this class but when I tried to show all categories in *configuration (system.xml)* then it only shows me default category. How can I show all categories in `system.xml` using this class